# Can someone explain Kohana 3's routing system?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes, kohana

In `bootstrap.php`, where you set routes, I'm having a hard time getting them to work. I read some documentation a while ago that I can't seem to find again that explains them. Here is one of my examples

```
Route::set('products', 'products/(type)', array('type' => '.+'))
    ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'articles',
    'action' => 'view_product',
    'page' => 'shock-absorbers',
    ));
```

I *thought* that would mean a request like `products/something` would load up the `articles` controller, and the `action_view_product()` method. But I can't get it to work.

Can someone please explain to me exactly how they work, and what all the method parameters are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought that would mean a request
>   like products/something would load up
>   the articles controller, and the
>   **action_view_product controller**. But I
>   can't get it to work.

You got the bolded part wrong. It will actually load action_view_product **method** of the articles controller:

```
class Controller_Articles extends Controller {
   public function action_view_product() {
       $params = $this->request->param(); 
       // if the uri is `products/something' then $params['type'] == 'something'
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Oh my god oh your god why didn't I notice!!!

The actual problem lies within your route pattern! It should have been `products/(<type>)`, with the angle brackets. Those will hint Kohana that you intended the 'type' to be a parameter name, instead of a literal.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! I still can't seem to get it to work for me.

Comment: Yes, I have a default route that is capturing all (and working alright)

Comment: did you declare this custom route before the default route? because the routing will match the first route it encounters, and since the default route will match 'products/something', it will take that route.

Answer (score 3):

uff, sorry, lower then and greater then signs doesn't shows correctly

```
'products/(type)' should be 'products/(<type>)'
```

Comment: or even better: `'product(/<type>)'`, because otherwise 'product' (without slash) wouldn't be matched (although you might want it that way)

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses indicate optional parts (the regex will match if they are missing). These can be static and/or contain named variables. The angle brackets indicate a named variable in the route which is accessible in the controller via:

```
$this->request->param('type');
```

I wrote the official routing guide which you can read [here](http://v3.kohanaphp.com/guide/tutorials.urls), it should answer all of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

For the record:

The directory, controller and action can be accessed from the Request as public properties like so:

> ```
> // From within a controller:
> $this->request->action;
> $this->request->controller;
> $this->request->directory;
>
> // Can be used anywhere:
> Request::instance()->action;
> Request::instance()->controller;
> Request::instance()->directory;
> ```

source: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing#request-parameters